# How to select next 3 values and last 3 values for a pivot point in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Have data in csv dataframe where i have a column pivot = 5 value

```
  price

1        
2         
3    
4        
5    
6     
7    
8    
9    
10
```

As pivot point is 5 , select pivot + next 3 values in price (6,7,8) and last 3 values 4,3,2 using pandas dataframe and

```
[output : 235678
```

Comment: `idx = df[df['price']==5].index[0]; df[idx-2:idx+3]['price'].tolist()`

Answer (score 1):

For the most reliable result, use the functions in the numpy library:

Sample Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'price': range(0,11)
}, index=list('ABCDEFGHIJK'))

   price
A      0
B      1
C      2
D      3
E      4
F      5
G      6
H      7
I      8
J      9
K     10
```

Code:

```
prices = df['price'].values

# Get the first index of prices where value is 5
index = np.argwhere(prices == 5).flat[0]

# Joining the values together
"".join([str(p) for p in prices[iloc-3:iloc+4]])
```